# What do * / ( and [ mean in the rfc 3986 URI syntax description?

Tags: rfc3986

Reading through the URI syntax description ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)) and trying to understand what their syntax descriptions mean.

For example, a URI has to have a schema part, which is restricted by the following syntax description:

```
scheme      = ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )
```

But the specification never tells you what * ( and / mean. Anything in quotations seems to mean exactly that character and ALPHA and DIGIT are seemingly the sets of ASCII characters pertaining to the alphanumeric set. I am guessing / is an or, ( may be a group, and * may be 0 or more. But it is not clarified in the specification.

There are other syntax descriptions like:

```
URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

I am also guessing the [ means that part is optional.

Does anybody know if my interpretation is correct? And would you be able to point me to the RFC specification of these characters?

Comment: Check [RFC 2234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2234) as mentioned in chapter 1.3.  Syntax Notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all well described in [RFC 5234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234) which is the Augmented BNF format.

- `/` is for [alternatives](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#section-3.2)
- `*` is for [variable repitition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234#section-3.6)

Answer (score 0):

It is a grammar Backus-Naur-like grammar.